# Odoo 17 Create Database Database creation error: Access Denied

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-17

I installed Odoo 17 and when creating a database access was denied

```
Database creation error: Access Denied
```

I have tried to configure debian\odoo.conf like this, but still access denied

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = user
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5433
db_user = odoo17
db_password = user
;addons_path = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons
addons_path = addons
default_productivity_apps = True
xmlrpc_port = 8069
```

Comment: Check if your User in Postgresql has the permission to create database.

Comment: in my Postgresql pgadmin User create database is enabeled but still access denied